# Printing from a part of a string without knowing its position

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a Discord bot that display Epic free games using data from an RSS feed.

```
import feedparser

epicfeed = feedparser.parse("https://steamcommunity.com/groups/freegamesfinders/rss/")
print(epicfeed.entries[0].description)
```

and it outputs a very long description

```
If you weren't around for Epicmas 2020, you're getting another chance to claim Cities: Skylines for free from the Epic store.<br /><br /><a class="bb_link" href="https://steamcommunity.com/linkfilter/?url=https://www.epicgames.com/store/en-US/p/cities-skylines" rel="noreferrer" target="_blank">Link</a><span class="bb_link_host">[www.epicgames.com]</span><br /><br />Details:<br />- Account/DRM required: Epic Games (NOT Steam)<br />- Offer good through March 17, 1600 GMT<br />- <a class="bb_link" href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/255710/Cities_Skylines/" rel="noreferrer" target="_blank">Steam store page</a> for evaluation<br /><br />There are also three always free DLC to claim once you have the base game:  Match Day, Pearls from the East, and Carols, Candles and Candy.<br /><br />Next week: In Sound Mind.<br /><br />LH<br />So... it's not a movie tie-in alien invasion DLC for the FTP game Cities?
```

The important part is this:

```
href="https://steamcommunity.com/linkfilter/?url=https://www.epicgames.com/store/en-US/p/cities-skylines"
```

I'm trying separate this Epicgames direct link (https://www.epicgames.com/store/en-US/p/cities-skylines)

Comment: Do you want just one of the links (i.e. the one with `linkfilter`) or either one is fine?

Comment: No just the direct link to Epicgames. The steam link takes you to a redirect page which would be annoying to click every time